# The count of good "words"

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many good $words$ are there , which have length $n$ and consist of {0,1}

A $word$ is considered good if the number of occurrences of $0$ in the $word$ is $even$:

ex.
$${ 
n = 3: [111],[100],[010],[001]
 }$$

I have no idea what to do.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hint: Arrange the words of length n in pairs, so that the words in each pair are the same except for the first digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need all the possible combinations that have `0, 2, 4, ... up to n` digits of zero.
Number of possible numbers with `0` digits is $\binom{n}{0}$, number of possible numbers with `2` digits $\binom{n}{2}$, and so on. 
After you sum up all these numbers, you get all the possible numbers that have from `0` to `n` even digits of 0.

$$\sum_{i=0}^\frac{n}{2}\binom{n}{2i}$$